# PostGIS geography conversion not working

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am new to PostGIS and QGIS. I am trying to convert geom to geog and then cast it back to geom in order to buffer my streets by 1,000 ft with this query:

```
SELECT a.gid, (st_buffer(a.geom::geography,304.8)::geometry) as geom, a.street_ext
FROM public.orangeburgroads a
JOIN public.orangeburg b ON st_within(st_centroid(a.geom), b.geom)
LIMIT 1000;
```

And here is what I am getting:

[image]

Does anyone have a clue why I am getting this result?

FYI *orangeburg* is a municipal boundary and *orangeburgroads* is a street center-line file.

[image]

Comment: SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(geom)) FROM orangeburgroads LIMIT 1;

Comment: You are joining the buffers with the output of ST_Within. You are not keeping the original record ids and therefore the query joins buffer 1 with the first element from the output from ST_Within. That brings your whole allocation in disorder.

Comment: Just curious: Why are you converting to geog? It shouldn't be needed, at least not in this way.

Comment: @tilt I am converting so that I can use meters as a buffer unit instead of degrees.

Comment: I suggested the query about because I suspect you have an SRID/coordinate mismatch, but I cannot tell if you don't post the output.

Comment: @PaulRamsey I have posted the output above.

Comment: Took me a while to see that the output was in the screenshot ;-) Your points already seem to be in a meters grid, so no need to do a conversion. What happens if you do just   st_buffer(a.geom,304.8) ?

Comment: @tilt that seems to have done the trick! but I don't understand how I can be in 4326 and it automatically know to use meters?

Comment: It's not in 4326. You may have loaded it as such, but those coordinates are definitely not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coordinates of your data are not geographic, they are Stateplane, SC, Feet, [EPSG:3361](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3361/). I know this because I used your test coordinate and back-projected it to geographics, to see if I landed in Orangeburg:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(
  'SRID=3361;POINT(1940865 660341)'::geometry, 4326));
```

Fix your data, first of all (do this for all the tables where you have projected coordinates, but an SRID of 4326):

```
ALTER TABLE orangeburgroads 
  ALTER COLUMN geom 
  TYPE Geometry(MultiLineString, 3361)
  USING ST_SetSRID(geom, 3361);
```

Now, knowing that your coordinates are in feet, just do your buffer query with that knowledge and skipping the trip into geography:

```
SELECT 
  a.gid, 
  ST_Buffer(a.geom,304.8) AS geom, 
  a.street_ext
FROM public.orangeburgroads a
JOIN public.orangeburg b 
ON ST_Intersects(ST_Centroid(a.geom), b.geom)
LIMIT 1000;
```